# при установки darling выдаёт этот текст

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake, gif

я так понял нужны GIF_LIBRARY GIF_INCLUDE_DIR я некоторые библиотеки связанные с gif скачал, но не помогло. $GIF_DIR -  тоже пустая переменная. XRandR установлен и работает, проверил. Подскажите пожалуйста что нужно?

```
CMake Warning at cmake/dsym.cmake:48 (message):
  Cannot find llvm-dsymutil, will not produce debug information
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:174 (FindDsymutil)

-- Compiler include path detected as /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/
FATALXRandR not found


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find GIF (missing: GIF_LIBRARY GIF_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindGIF.cmake:109 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  src/external/cocotron/Onyx2D/CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 0):

Чат gpt помог, лол. Вот ответ:
Hello Олег! It seems like you're encountering an error related to the GIF library while using CMake. Let's take a closer look at the situation and explore some potential solutions.

The error message suggests that CMake couldn't find the GIF library, specifically the GIF_LIBRARY and GIF_INCLUDE_DIR. This means that the required files for the GIF library are missing or not set up correctly on your system.

Here are a few steps you can follow to address this issue:

1. Verify if the GIF library is installed: Check if the GIF library is installed on your system. You can do this by running the following command in your terminal:

   ```
   dpkg -l | grep libgif-dev
   ```

   If the output is empty, it means the library is not installed. In that case, you can install it using the package manager specific to your operating system. For example, on Ubuntu, you can run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgif-dev
   ```
2. Verify the library paths: If the GIF library is installed, but CMake still can't find it, you might need to specify the library paths manually. In your CMakeLists.txt file, before the `find_package(GIF ...)` line, you can add the following lines:

   ```
   set(GIF_LIBRARY /path/to/gif/library)
   set(GIF_INCLUDE_DIR /path/to/gif/include)
   ```

   Replace `/path/to/gif/library` and `/path/to/gif/include` with the actual paths where the GIF library and include files are located on your system.
3. CMake configuration: If the previous steps didn't resolve the issue, there might be an issue with the CMake configuration itself. You can try deleting the CMakeCache.txt file (if it exists) in your project's build directory and reconfigure your project using CMake.

   ```
   rm /path/to/your/project/build/CMakeCache.txt
   cd /path/to/your/project/build
   cmake ..
   ```

   This will regenerate the CMakeCache.txt file and reconfigure your project.

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the "Could NOT find GIF" error. If you have any further questions or encounter any difficulties, feel free to ask for assistance.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).